# How to execute a shell script in C?

Tags: c, shell

I'm trying to create a .sh file, write the script to it and then execute it using exec*

So far, I managed to create the file and write the code to it, but the execl doesn't execute the script

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] ){
    char str[] = "#!/bin/bash \n echo 'Hello World!'";
    FILE *fp = fopen("script.sh", "w+");
    fwrite(str , 1 , sizeof(str) , fp );
    fclose(fp);
    execl ("/usr/bin/chmod", "chmod", "+x", "script.sh", (char *)0);
    execl ("/export/home/redpal/lab4", "script.sh", (char *)0);
    return 0;
}
```

Should I put each execl in the child proccess?

Comment: Maybe not the only answer out there, but the way I ran a shell script, the shell script requires its own process id, so I used `fork` to create a child process and `waitpid` for the parent process to wait on the child process to complete. Then within the child process block statement (in an if/else type statement), I used `execve` to execute the script.

Comment: `execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", chr, NULL);`. No need to write `script.sh` to disk at all, or futz with that file's permissions, or do anything else. (Of course, this **will** end/exit your program, like any successful `exec`-family call).

Comment: Why do you generate a shell script and why do you want to execute it ? What is your real program intended to do?

Comment: That's it. That's the problem my lecturer gave to me. Create a program which generates .sh script and executes it. The task is from a chapter about exec, so I have to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `execl` function (like all [exec(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) functions and the [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) system call) **don't return on success**. It would return only on failure.

So your first call:

```
execl ("/usr/bin/chmod", "chmod", "+x", "script.sh", (char *)0);
```

is very likely to succeed. Then your current program is gone, and your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) is running the `/usr/bin/chmod` program. Once that program finished (in a few milliseconds), your process exits (and your invoking shell gives a new prompt).

Instead of using the `/usr/bin/chmod` *program* you should consider using the [chmod(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html) system call.

The rest of your program is also wrong. You might want to `exec` the generated script (but then, you need to give its entire path).

You need to understand how to run processes using [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) and friend system calls. We cannot explain how to do that (it is too long), but you should read several chapters of the [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) book (freely downloadable).

Perhaps you should consider embedding an interpreter like [Lua](http://lua.org/) or [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) in your real program (so your question looks like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/))

And you might just use [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) or [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) to run some command.... Perhaps using something like `FILE* cmd = popen("/bin/sh", "w");` might be enough .... Then you'll write shell commands to `cmd` and you need to `pclose(cmd)`

Comment: Wait, why not keep it simple and use `system()`?

Answer (score 2):

Check for errors after each potentially failing command.
You should write `sizeof(array)-1` bytes into the file, or you'll be also writing the terminating zero.

`exec*` syscalls replace process images. If they succeed, your program is replaced by the binary you've just executed. Consequently, you either need to exec in a child process or the `exec*` syscall needs to be the last thing you do in your program.

In your case, the `chmod` execution is entirely avoidable. You can either issue the `chmod` syscall directly, or you can make sure you create the file in which case you can set the permissions right off the bat.

I'd it like so:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    unlink("script.sh"); //unchecked -- let it fail if the file's not there
    int fd;
    if(0>(fd = open("script.sh", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0777)))
        { perror("Couldn't create 'script.sh'"); return EXIT_FAILURE; }
    int nr;
    static char const str[] = "#!/bin/bash \n echo 'Hello World!'";
    size_t to_write = sizeof str - 1;
    if( to_write != (nr=write(fd, str, sizeof str - 1)) || 0>close(fd)  )
        { perror("Couldn't write contents"); return EXIT_FAILURE; }
    //writes to the filesystem on linux aren't ever partial unless there's a filesystem error 
    //otherwise you need to account for partial write (which fwrite does for you)

    execl ("./script.sh", "script.sh", (char *)0);
    perror("Couldn't exec './script.sh'");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```